# VBA Code in thisoutlooksession wouldn't work

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have the below vba coding in thisoutlooksession in outlook.

Basically this coding pops up a yes/no message box for all outgoing E-mails external to my organisation.

The coding works file, However, thisoutlooksession sometimes doesn't recognize that it has a coding in it.

However, when i open the coding window (Alt + F11) and place a break in the header, and run the coding, it starts working fine after that.

I have double/triple checked, there is no problem with the coding. it is something to do with the settings.

I have enabled all macros as well.

Any suggestions or thoughts as why this happens and how could this be overcome?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next

If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub

Dim sCompanyDomain As String: sCompanyDomain = "tell.com"

Const PidTagSmtpAddress As String =     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

On Error Resume Next

Dim oMail As MailItem: Set oMail = Item
Dim oRecipients As Recipients: Set oRecipients = oMail.Recipients
Dim bDisplayMsgBox As Boolean: bDisplayMsgBox = False

Dim sExternalAddresses As String
Dim oRecipient As Recipient

For Each oRecipient In oRecipients

Dim oProperties As PropertyAccessor: Set oProperties =     oRecipient.PropertyAccessor
    Dim smtpAddress As String: smtpAddress =     oProperties.GetProperty(PidTagSmtpAddress)

    Debug.Print smtpAddress

    If (Len(smtpAddress) >= Len(sCompanyDomain)) Then

    If (Right(LCase(smtpAddress), Len(sCompanyDomain)) <> sCompanyDomain)     Then

' external address found
            If (sExternalAddresses = "") Then

            sExternalAddresses = smtpAddress

        Else

            sExternalAddresses = sExternalAddresses & ", " & smtpAddress

        End If

        bDisplayMsgBox = True

    End If

End If

Next

If (bDisplayMsgBox) Then

Dim iAnswer As Integer
iAnswer = MsgBox("You are about to send this email externally to " & sExternalAddresses & vbCr & vbCr & "Do you want to continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "External Email Check")

If (iAnswer = vbNo) Then
    Cancel = True
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "thisoutlooksession sometimes doesn't recognize that it has a coding in it"  -- what does that mean?

Comment: Sometimes the coding wouldn't just work.

Comment: How did you subscribe to the ItemSend event? See the similar forum thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673582/outlook-open-form-via-vba-makro-and-send-mail-with-settings-of-thisoutlooksessi

Comment: Eugene, I used Private Sub Application_Itemsend to start with..

Comment: Whether or not it has any impact, there is something wrong with the coding. Remove the  On Error Resume Next statements and see what happens. Do not put them back unless there is a reason and follow as closely as possible with On Error GoTo 0.

Comment: Thanks Niton. The coding works fine even without 'ON ERROR RESUME NEXT'. Again, as i understand, its something to do with the event handler..

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort move the otm file to a backup folder.

Start Outlook to find an empty otm. Copy the code above into ThisOutlookSession.